# Listview with Edittextbox

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

i'm new to android.I want to add values to the listview as below.I have done list views using static arrays.but now i want to add value to the listview as a user inputs.Could someone please tell me the way to insert user input values in this case? If you have any worked through examples, that would be a real help!

```
        **Add Title   [Edit Textbox 1]
        Add values  [Edit textbox 2]
        ..........Listview...................
        Title 1
        values 1
        Title  2
        values 2**
```

Comment: Just googled, you can find many example like this, And try your self by android sample examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Costume Adapter help full to you

Comment: Glad that my written information can be helpful to someone :)